# Python TKinter read only texbox not showing the content

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I'm using TKinter in Pycharm.

this is the code of a text box in a form:

```
value_close_open_short = round((np.round(Results_short.iloc[level_short].open_low, 3)) * 100, 2)
close_open_short_box = tk.Entry(root, state="readonly")
close_open_short_box.insert(tk.INSERT, value_close_open_short)
close_open_short_box.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

value_close_open_short exists and is correct.

However, the text box is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initialising the `Entry` object as `readonly` and then attempting to write to it, which the widget blocks. Instead, you should initialise the entry, insert into the entry, and then set it to readonly.

```
import tkinter as tk

#placeholder value
value_close_open_short = 10

root = tk.Tk()
close_open_short_box = tk.Entry(root)
close_open_short_box.insert(tk.INSERT, value_close_open_short)
close_open_short_box.config(state="readonly")
close_open_short_box.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```